# Search Sublime Text 2 for files that contain 'Mickey' but do not contain 'Mouse'

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Is it possible to carry out a search in Sublime Text 2 for files that contain `'Mickey'`

but do not contain `'Mouse'`.

Regular expressions maybe? But what would they be?

Comment: Are you looking to exclude files that contain `Mickey Mouse` or `Mickey some text Mouse` or `Mouse named Mickey`?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you could use regex to do this, using the [negative lookahead expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Open the Search `Ctrl-Shift-F`

Make sure you Search with Regular Expressions `Alt-R`

```
Mickey(?! Mouse)
```

Would return all instances of '`Mickey`' that were not followed by '`Mouse`'

**NOTE**: *make sure you include the space before* `Mouse`!

Comment: What about cases where Mouse comes before Mickey? You need to cover that too.

Comment: ST2 is not ready at hand, so I used Notepad++.  I was able to make this work with some tweaking: `^(?!.*Mickey.*Mouse).*`  (With Tom Lord's observation still applied, but I'm sure a big OR construct will answer that.)

Answer (score 2):

Is the fact that you use this particular text editor really important? Personally, I'd just do it using grep. Something like:

```
grep -l Mickey filename | xargs grep -L Mouse
```

Explanation:

The -l option means "print the filename(s) that contain a match, not the matching lines".

xargs passes these matching filename(s) into the next grep command.

The -L option means "print the filename(s) that don't contain a match, not the matching lines".

You can then run this command on multiple files, simultaneously - perhaps by adding a -r ("recursive") option to the first grep.

Comment: "Is the fact that you use this particular text editor really important?" Heh heh... grep is wonderful, but Sublime Text has a captivating, addicting quality, especially for those who are new to powers like regex.  I know my answer would be "Yes, it's important."

Comment: Haha... I didn't mean that as in "that's not a good text editor" - it was more intended as a way of saying "You don't actually need a text editor to do this..." (And in fact, using grep like I have done, from the command line, gives you the advantage that you can easily search multiple files at once.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the regular expression offered by `Smandoli`, but it actually crashed `Sublime Text 2`!

Maybe its a problem with one of the `Sublime` plugins I've added, I simply don't know.

The reason I wanted to use `Sublime` to do the search is that I'm working on a reasonably large project with well over a thousand files. So I want to search the project for files containing a particular string ('Mickey'). Edit the file if necessary and add the word Mouse. Then I could 'refresh' the search which would now omit the file I just edited because it no longer fits the search criteria. Its a reasonable work flow.

```
    Note: The strings are not actually Mickey and Mouse, I just used those to illustrate 
the problem. I don't work for Disney :)
```

Because the `regex` offered by `Smandoli` crashed `Sublime` I also tried the `grep` command offered by `Tom Lord` (I'm running on `Windows 7`) but couldn't see a way to only target files with a particular extension (`*.asp`)

In the end I wrote a small `Powershell` script that seems to do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -like "*.asp"}
    ForEach-Object { if( ( $(Get-Content $_) |
                            select-string -pattern "Mickey") )
                     { $_.PsPath }} | Get-ChildItem |
    ForEach-Object { if( !( $(Get-Content $_) |
                            select-string -pattern "Mouse") )
                     { $_.PsPath }}
```

Comment: I just ran into this problem in Sublime, I'm looking into alternatives. Any suggestions? I'd prefer to stay in Sublime, otherwise I'm willing to move to the command line. I'm about to try grep.